# Averaging an Array of Tensors in Python with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm doing a project with StyleGans and I actually don't really know Python very well or Numpy

I have an array of vector

```
final_b_vectors = np.array(final_b_vectors) // final_b_vectors is an ndarray with shape (14, 18, 512)
```

I want to find the average value of the array

I currently use

```
averageB = final_b_vectors[0] + final_b_vectors[1] + final_b_vectors[2] + final_b_vectors[3] + final_b_vectors[4] + final_b_vectors[5] + final_b_vectors[6] + final_b_vectors[7] + final_b_vectors[8] + final_b_vectors[9] + final_b_vectors[10] + final_b_vectors[11]  + final_b_vectors[12] + final_b_vectors[13]
averageB = averageB /14
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this using loops or function in numpy but I'm having problems searching for an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
avg = final_b_vectors.mean(axis = 0)
```

Comment: That worked and is much easier to maintain.

Comment: I would suggest you to read the numpy docs on things like axis, dimension, indexing and basic functions on multidimensional arrays. It would be very helpful if you are familiar with them.